# CMake how to include headers without sources?

Tags: c++, cmake, header-files

This is probably a dummy question but I have literally looked at the two first pages of google without success.
I'm writing a header only library and I'm unable to set up correctly the CMake configuration in order that when I build my solution a given `main.cpp` finds the proper includes.
How can this be accomplished?

**EDIT**

So I probably should give a little more detailed explanation.
Lets say I have a `./src` folder with: `./src/core` and `./src/wrappers`. Inside each folder I have `.h` files that needs to be included in a `main.cpp` file:

```
#include <src/core/reader.h>
```

Still when I put in `CMakeList.txt` something like:

```
include_directories(src/core)
add_executable(main main.cpp)
```

I receive a message like: `src/core/reader.h` no such file or directory.

Answer (score 10):

To be able to use that path, you should refer to the parent directory of `src`.
Assuming the top level `CMakeLists.txt` is at the same level of `src`, you can use this instead:

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
```

As from the documentation of `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`:

> The path to the top level of the source tree.

If `src` is directly in the top level directory, this should let you use something like:

```
#include <src/whatever/you/want.h>
```

---

That said, a couple of suggestions:

- I would rather add this:

  ```
  include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
  ```

  And use this:

  ```
  #include <whatever/you/want.h>
  ```

  No longer `src` in your paths and restricted search area.
- I would probably use `target_include_directories` instead of `include_directories` and specify the *target* to be used for that rules:

  ```
  target_include_directories(main ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
  ```

  This must be put after the `add_executable`, otherwise the target is not visible.

Comment: @Jairo Well, feel free to vote up or accept the answer if it works. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Another option which might make sense in some situations would be to create a dedicated target for the header-only library:

```
add_library(headerlib INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(headerlib INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

And then to use it:

```
target_link_libraries(mytarget headerlib)
```

This has the advantage that if you want to use it in multiple targets, it's easy to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a [`include_directories()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html) directive in order to find where your header only library can be found by the target project.

---

According to your edit. To find

```
 #include <src/core/reader.h>
```

You need to add

```
 include_directories(/full_parent_path_of_src)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then in your CMakeLists.txt you need to add `include_directories(<DIRECTORY>)` for every directory of your header library.